# UITableViewCell Position Off After Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-animation

I have an animation going on in `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)`. The cells essentially rotate in (code below). They do this every time they load onto the screen. The cells that rotate in initially (that is, the ones visible on screen at the beginning) look like the "Before" snapshot below. Small (normal) indentation. After scrolling down or around, new cells are animated onto the screen, but they look like the "After" shot. They're off by a few pixels. Once I scroll up again, the upper cells are reloaded and also have the larger indentation. All of which would be fine, except depending on scroll behavior, sometimes some cells are indented and others aren't and it looks awful. I tried resetting the indent property of `UITableViewCell` but it didn't do anything. Any ideas what could cause this odd behavior? Perhaps a property I'm not aware of I should be setting? Thanks!

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

```
//Animation Code Borrowed From http://www.thinkandbuild.it/animating-uitableview-cells/
//1. Setup the CATransform3D structure
CATransform3D rotation;
rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (90.0*M_PI)/180, 0.0, 0.7, 0.4);
rotation.m34 = 1.0/ -600;

//2. Define the initial state (Before the animation)
cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
cell.alpha = 0;

cell.layer.transform = rotation;
cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);

//3. Define the final state (After the animation) and commit the animation
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotation" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
cell.alpha = 1;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

**EDIT**
After going to the original site's source code again, I noticed an update to the code and I applied it:

```
if(cell.layer.position.x != 0){
    cell.layer.position = CGPointMake(0, cell.layer.position.y);
}
```

However, it didn't seem to fix this issue, and I think it was a fix for another positioning issue this animation had.

Comment: try by setting the position of the layer programatically

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure just give it a try,

just by forcing the layer position to origin, see below code

```
//1. Setup the CATransform3D structure
CATransform3D rotation;
rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (90.0*M_PI)/180, 0.0, 0.7, 0.4);
rotation.m34 = 1.0/ -600;


//2. Define the initial state (Before the animation)
cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
cell.alpha = 0;

cell.layer.transform = rotation;
cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);

if(cell.layer.position.x != 0)
{
    cell.layer.position = CGPointMake(0, cell.layer.position.y);
}

//add this and try
CGPoint point = cell.layer.position;
point.x = 0.0f; //setting the position back to original (for your case)
cell.layer.position = point;


//4. Define the final state (After the animation) and commit the animation
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotation" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
cell.alpha = 1;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, after trying, the same behavior occurs :(

Comment: just log and check the position of each cell after and before animation

Comment: Just did! It returns 0.000000 for all of them before and after, including the clearly offset cells. What could that mean?!

Comment: u mean u did like this   `NSLog(@"x->%f,y->%f",cell.layer.position.x,cell.layer.position.y);` the position of y may change but x position will give zero

Comment: Yep! That's exactly right. I expected to see some slightly different value for the offending cells, but instead it also returned 0. Which makes me wonder if the problem isn't the cell's position, but some padding property it might have?